# Sitecore Email Experience manager option not displayed in dashboard

Tags: sitecore8.2

I am working with Sitecore 8.2(Sitecore 8.2 rev. 170614), i have installed exm (Email Experience Manager 3.4.2 rev. 170713). It has been completely installed and then sitecore client has restarted.

I have also followed the instruction written to follow when EXM installation completes but i am not able to see EXM option in Sitecore launchpad or dashboard.

Is there any other settings needs to be done?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following entries in your connection string and need to create the database for exm.master and exm.web and generate key for exm.CryptographicKey and EXM.AuthenticationKey. Please let me know if this is not clear or need more info.

```
<add name="exm.master" connectionString="Data Source
<add name="exm.web" connectionString="Data Source=
<add name="EXM.CryptographicKey" connectionString= "
<add name="EXM.AuthenticationKey" connectionString=
```